# Show $\mu$ cannot be a measure

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

[image]

Consider $A=\left(\frac 14, \frac 12\right)\cap\mathcal X\in\mathcal A$. $\mu\left(A\right)=\frac 12-\frac 14=\frac 14$. But now consider $\left(\frac 14, .3\right)\cap\mathcal X$ and $\left[.3, \frac 12\right)\cap \mathcal X$. $\mu\left(\left(\frac 14, .3\right)\cap\mathcal X\right)=.3-\frac 14$ and $\mu\left(\left[.3, \frac 12\right)\cap \mathcal X\right)>\frac 12-.3$ infinitesimally, as we must take the largest rational number less than .3. Thus $\mu\left(\left(\frac 14, .3\right)\cap\mathcal X \cup\left[.3, \frac 12\right)\cap \mathcal X\right)>\frac 14=\mu\left(A\right)$ and is not a measure.

I wasn't sure if this is right because of the infinitesimal part.

Comment: There is no largest rational number less than $0.3$

Comment: But your approach is salvageable.  You have $\mu\left(\left(\frac 14, \frac 12\right)\right)=\frac14 = \mu\left(\left(\frac 14, 0.3\right)\cap\mathcal X\right)+\mu\left(\left(0.3, \frac 12\right)\cap \mathcal X\right)$ so $\mu\left(0.3\right)=0$ and similarly for all other rationals.  There are a countably infinite number of rationals in $(0,1)$ so the measure of their union is the sum of their measures, which would mean $0= \mu(\mathcal X)=\mu\left(\left(0,1\right)\cap\mathcal X\right)=1$

Comment: @Henry. Oh. Re your first comment, so since $[0.3, \frac 12)\in\mathcal A$, and $\mu$ is not defined for it, it is not a measure basically?

Comment: Hint: What would the "measure" of a singleton point be, if this worked?

Comment: Since $0.3$ is a rational, $\mu(0.3)$ could be found for it if $\mu$ was a measure, and since you can take finite or countable unions you would have $\mu\left(\left[0.3, \frac 12\right)\cap \mathcal X\right)= \mu(0.3)+\mu\left(\left(0.3, \frac 12\right)\cap \mathcal X\right)$

Comment: @Henry thank you that is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof idea will not work, because it misses the fundamental reason $\mu$ cannot be a measure.

A measure must be countably-additive, but the rationals are countable.  This suggests we can find a contradiction, and so we'll assume that $\mu$ is a measure.

Any countable set is a countable union of singleton sets; we can conclude from this that $\mu$ cannot assign the same value to every singleton set, and further that there must exist some $a \in \chi$ such that $\mu({a}) > 0$.

Imagine some interval $I$ containing $a$.  We can remove $a$ from this interval by removing an arbitrarily-small neighborhood around it - and thus decreasing $\mu(I)$ by an arbitrarily-small amount.  But removing $a$ must decrease $\mu(I)$ by at least $\mu(a)$, so this is impossible.